# How to add inner border to bootstrap 3 nav-tabs with transparent background?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't figure out how to hide .tab-pane's overlapping border. I tried clipping it but it still is visible.

Does anyone know of any jQuery plugins that can hide the bottom border?

Please see fiddle at the bottom.

[image]

## HTML

```
<section id="content" class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="tab-forms col-md-12">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab"
                                                      data-toggle="tab">SIGN UP</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SIGN
                IN</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                <div class="form-border">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
                <div class="form-border">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

## CSS

```
body {
  background: #155C91;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 88px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.tab-forms .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.tab-forms .nav-tabs li.active a {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 144px 0px, 144px 81px, 0px 81px);
  /*Chrome,Safari*/
  /*Firefox*/
}
.tab-forms .nav-tabs li.active a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 90%;
  height: 55px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.tab-forms .nav-tabs li.active a:after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  content: "";
  width: 127px;
  height: 55px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 7px;
  position: absolute;
}
.tab-forms .nav-tabs li a {
  margin-right: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  width: 144px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
.tab-forms .nav-tabs li a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 80%;
  height: 25px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 11%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.tab-forms .tab-content {
  padding: 8px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.tab-forms .tab-content .tab-pane {
  border: 1px solid #ffff00;
  min-height: 100px;
}
rect {
  fill: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/12901/

https://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/12908/

Comment: set `border-bottom: none;` for `.tab-forms .nav-tabs li.active a::after`

Comment: I did that and it just showed the .tab-pane border which in fiddle is colored yellow.

Comment: You could remove the border-bottom, but the border for the tab-pane would still be visible ...? It would not make any difference now you have semi-transparent layout.

Comment: I think via SVG will make this possible. Will update question when I switch this to svg tabs. If you guys find any svg tabs similar to this one please link us.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border-bottom` property from `.tab-forms .nav-tabs li.active a:after` and set `border-bottom:none;` for `.tab-forms .nav-tabs li.active a:before`

Comment: can you share with fiddle?

Comment: here is the fiddle to your answer. http://jsfiddle.net/4oq218fz/ If this is not what you mean please modify and share. It shows the yellow border and I need to remove that space to make the tab look like a file folder.